# Looking for QGIS Presentation info

Tags: qgis, history

I'm preparing a presentation of QGIS to release of the brazilian QGIS user guide. Thus, I would like insert some information about QGIS in global scale. Something like Tim's qgis-for-humanity presentation, but with updated information.
I'm very pleasure if you have something in this direction to send me.

Comment: Please be more specific about what kind of information you are looking for. The presentation you mention contains a lot of different information. Also, it's from Nov 2011, not that old yet.

Comment: Something like downloads and versions, timeline releases, global users distribution, communities in other countries...

Answer (score 1):

The latest "official" numbers on downloads and distributions are available through http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/19/qgis-users-around-the-world/

> In the case of QGIS, we can track the total number of downloads from qgis.org, but this doesn’t represent the total installed base. It is impossible to accurately determine the actual number of people using QGIS, ...
>
> So how many people use QGIS? At the very minimum, 35,000. We know that the downloads of just the Windows version exceeded 100,000.

Wikipedia has a list of release dates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qgis

The developer community is very international and not centered in any specific country. There are different user communities focusing on different language regions like e.g. the German-speaking users which have been holding annual meetings in different Switzerland.

Comment: Tks. Inserted to presentation.